# Missing unblock button under properties

Tags: php, windows, file, phpmyadmin, block

So im trying to setup all of the PHP, MYSQL, APACHE, and PHPMYADMIN. To do this, im following a guide, because I obviously cant do this completely on my own... Im actually almost done setting this up, and now i stumple upon another problem. The thing is, i have to unblock certain programs(for example the php.exe file), but i do not even have the "unblock" button.

Is there any other way you can "unblock" the file?

=========================================================================
Screenshot:
http://gyazo.com/6d20d1e1785b25b1f0fd46c601f34d6e

^Yes I know the language is danish.. But there should be an unblock button right beneath the "avanceret"(advanced) button.

Thank you

Comment: How are you so sure the files are blocked in the first place?

Answer (score 10):

I've often ran into this same problem when downloading files.  Windows will not always display the unblock button.  Here are a couple easy workarounds:

First to verify the file is actually blocked, open a command prompt and type:

`more < yourFile.exe:Zone.Identifier`

If it reports your file has a ZoneId = 3 or 4, your file is indeed blocked.  You have two easy options to unblock it:

First Method: If you have PowerShell version 3 or higher, you can open a PowerShell window and type:

`C:\>Unblock-File -Path C:\Path\ToFile\yourFile.exe`

To open a PowerShell window type `powershell` into the run box.
To check your PowerShell version, type this from the PowerShell prompt:

```
C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major
```

Second Method: If you don't have that version of PowerShell installed, you could install it for free but there is a much faster download.  Download the free streams program from sysinternals:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx
and from a command prompt type:

`streams -d C:\Path\ToFile\yourFile.exe`.

Note*

If these files were downloaded from the Internet in a .zip file and you unblock the zip file before unzipping, then all of it's contents will be unblocked as well.  If you forgot to do that before unzipping then add the -s option (in addition to -d) and run the above stream command on the parent directory itself instead of your file/s.  This will recursively unblock everything in the sub-directories.

Comment: GOOD!!! VERY USEFUL!!! THIS IS THE ONLY USEFUL POST THAT REALLY HELPS ME!!! THANK YOU!

Comment: I was able to unblock my application using the first step. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to unblock the php.exe, or httpd.exe or mysqld.exe.

You might have needed to unblock the installers, because you downloaded them from the internet.

But, since you obviously are here, with php.exe already on your computer - you must have clicked "Ok" to some question like "Are you sure you want to run this program?".

Comment: So if that is not the case, what do i then have to do here:
Screenshot:
http://gyazo.com/5cb2e4052808e8c1cc0298564bee8d24

^Dont mind my port is changed..

Comment: Enable mb_string extension in php.ini, restart apache.